# Dart 2: How to access a class's type?

Tags: dart

In Swift 4, I used to do something like this to locally store objects of variable classes:

```
class Repo {
  var mediaType : MyBaseClass.Type

  func doSomething() {
    mediaType.someStaticMethod();
  }
}

class SpecificClass : MyBaseClass {
    static func someStaticMethod() -> void {
      // Stuff
    }
}

repo = Repo(SpecificClass.self)
repo.doSomething();  // Executes `Stuff`
```

Moving to Dart 2, this is the closest I've gotten, yet the error specified at the bottom is blocking me.

```
class Repo {
  Type mediaType;

  void doSomething() {
    mediaType.someStaticMethod();
  }
}

class SpecificClass extends MyBaseClass {
  static void someStaticMethod() {
    // Whatever
  }
}

repo = Repo(SpecificClass)
repo.doSomething()  // Should execute `Whatever`, but for the error
```

Which generates this error:

```
The method 'someStaticMethod' isn't defined for the class 'Type'
```

Is this sort of trick feasible with Dart 2?

Comment: Instead of `Type mediaType;`, just use `MyBaseClass mediaType;`. It should work.

Comment: Using `MyBaseClass mediaType` expects an _instance_ of `BaseMediaType`, whereas I want to pass the class itself.

Comment: After a bit of search, it seems it is not possible in Dart: https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/34131

Comment: It seems it's that `.Type` and subsequent `.self` from Swift that are missing Dart equivalents and would seemingly easily allow for this.

Comment: You can use something like https://github.com/google/built_value.dart/blob/ff978e8ae1eeb41a08d2782ead35b83c81cc8afc/built_value/lib/serializer.dart#L190 to pass type information and you can closurize the constructor to pass it around `() => MyClass()`. It's a bit more boilerplate but otherwise there is hardly anything you can't do.